# JavaPlot (GNUPlot) set legend labels and axis name

Tags: java, gnuplot, javaplot

The current code i use is:

```
JavaPlot plotter = new JavaPlot();
plotter.setTitle("Title");

plotter.addPlot(data1);
plotter.addPlot(data1);



plotter.plot();
```

But I want to be able to set the labels in de legend (now they are: Datafile 1, Datafile2)
and also the name of the axis.

I've looked into the documentation of JavaPlot but I haven't found something.

Maybe something with GNUPlotParameters

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set gnuplot parameters with the JavaPlot.set(String, String) method.
In your example:

```
plotter.set("xlabel", "'x'");
```

Notice that you have to use "'x'" and not just "x".

For the plot title you can use the AbstractPlot.setTitle(String) method.

If you create your plot like this

```
double[][] data = new double[][] { { 0, 0 }, {1, 1}};
Plot data1 = new DataSetPlot(data);
```

then you can set the title by casting data1 to AbstractPlot

```
((AbstractPlot)data1).setTitle("'my title'");
```

or declare data1 as AbstractPlot right away

```
double[][] data = new double[][] { { 0, 0 }, {1, 1}};
AbstractPlot data1 = new DataSetPlot(data);
data1.setTitle("'my title'");
```